# Failure when using data.table in a package

Tags: r, package, data.table

Define the following function in a personal package `mypackage`:

```
#' test
#' @export
ff <-  function(dat){
  require(data.table)
  as.data.frame(data.table(dat)[, list(min=min(Date)), by="xx"])
}
```

Then this code runs fine:

```
library(mypackage)
dat <- cbind(iris, xx=gl(2,75), Date=3)
ff(dat)
```

But if `mypackage` is not loaded then this code fails:

```
> mypackage::ff(dat)
Loading required package: data.table
data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'Date' not found
```

I'd like to understand why and to know whether there is a workaround without loading the package.

Comment: You should remove that `require()` and declare `Imports: data.table` in the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Read [FAQ 6.9](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf).

Comment: There are exceptions, but in general you shouldn't have `require` or `library` calls in your package.

Comment: @Arun `data.table` was already included in the `Depends` field. The second solution of FAQ 6.9 works (`Imports` field **and** `import(data.table)` in the NAMESPACE. However I have a problem then: I'm using `roxygen` to build the documentation (with the RStudio panel), and this overwrites NAMESPACE.

Comment: Will need more to work on. What did you add (exactly) to `roxygen`, and what does it do? Have you read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html)? Seems like you should do `@import data.table`??

Comment: Check [this file](https://github.com/cran/repra/blob/master/R/help.R) for example..

Comment: @Arun Sorry I have never seen such things. I don't know what is this file `help.R` and I don't know where to write `@import data.table`.

Comment: @Arun I don't even see what you mean by "adding to roxygen". I'm only clicking on the "Document" and "Build" buttons in RStudio.

Comment: Sorry I meant what `roxygen` command did you add to your file. I'm not sure how you add documentation with `roxygen` by only clicking. I'm assuming you've R files, and you type at some point. And you'll have to create a "dummy" R file (ex: yourPackage.R) and add packages for your namespace. My experience with `roxygen` is limited. Seems like you've to read up on `roxygen`.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for you help. So far I have only used roxygen to write the documentations of the functions. You're right, I should take a look at the doc.